# Как получить имя модели телефона?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как получить список самых дорогих моделей телефонов каждого производителя? Сейчас выводит только id производителя и цену, не понимаю как получить имя модели

```
SELECT 
    companyId,
    max(price)
FROM phone
group by companyId;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный запрос выводит вам цену самого дорогого. Возьмите теперь селект на выборку моделей и компаний `from phone inner join company` и приджойньте туда вот этот ваш запрос по совпадению цены и производителя

Comment: @teran, это верно если вопрос бы звучал "название компании, модель и макс цена". А так просто `phoneModel` добавить в `select` и `group by`

Comment: @MaxDown *"самых дорогих моделей телефонов **каждого производителя**"*

Comment: @MaxDown если "так просто добавить phoneModel", то вы получите то же самое, что просто выборка `company,model, price`, ибо группировка по company,model вернет полный список и max будет работать с одной строкой

Comment: @teran, "каждого производителя" <> "название каждого производителя"

Comment: @teran, "вы получите то же самое" не уверен в этом. Сколько запросов делал с двойной группировкой, то всё гуд выдаёт

Comment: @teran, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dca0ed55cb6496a3f74cc221fae1c4f0

Comment: @MaxDown в вашем примере условно айфон 12 продается у разных продавцов и вы выбираете максимальную цену. Здесь же вопрос в том, что у эппла есть айфоны разных номеров, а у самсунга с-серия. Вот надо выбрать, что у эппла самый дорогой - 13й, а у самсунга с21, а не максимальные цены на всю продукцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос следует бить на два:

1. Как найти самую большую цену для каждого производителя (см. подзапрос или ваш вариант из вопроса)
2. У каждого производителя найти телефон с ценой из предыдущего шага

Вот ответ.

```
select c.company_name, 
       p.phone_model,
       p.price
  from phone p
  join company c
    on p.company_id = c.company_id
 where p.price = (select max(price) 
                    from phone p1 
                   where p1.company_id = p.company_id)   
 order by c.company_name, 
          p.phone_model;
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PopdQ4bcu2JRSvMAXVuVk/0) с моим примером.

В следующий раз, пожалста, добавьте к вопросу еще и тестовых данных, максимально похожих на продуктивные. Так выше шанс получить более подходящий под вашу ситуацию ответ

UPD. если у вас mySQL версии 8 и выше, можно воспользоваться CTE. Это сделает запрос, как минимум, более читаемым:

```
with max_prices as (
  select p.company_id, 
         c.company_name,
         max(p.price) max_price
    from phone p
    join company c
      on p.company_id = c.company_id
   group by company_id,
            company_name
)

select mp.*, 
       p.phone_model
  from max_prices mp
  join phone p
    on p.company_id = mp.company_id
   and p.price = mp.max_price;
```